# Error trying to compile simple "hello world" with OpenMPI on OpenSUSE

Tags: linux, gcc, mpi, openmpi, opensuse

I am learning MPA using OpenMPI on my classes, but I cannot seem to make it work on my laptop using OpenSUSE.

I got OpenMPI from https://software.opensuse.org/package/openmpi and when trying to compile using:

```
mpicc hello.c -o hello
```

I get the following error msg saying that it cannot find mpi.h:

```
hello.c:3:17: fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory
 #include "mpi.h"
                 ^
compilation terminated
```

Is there something that I am missing? If so, what exactly do I need to do to make this work out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to install openmpi-devel package:

```
zypper install openmpi-devel
```